# Multiple ngrx store instances in one application

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Is it possible to create an instance store for each component instance - as is the case with services by declaring the service in the providers array in the component decorator?

Comment: share some code and more description to understand what you want exactly .

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, [Managing different slices of the same NgRx state](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/managing-different-slices-of-the-same-ngrx-state).

You will have to create an instance per component:

```
{
  "counters": {
    "31cd7f19-559e-4d77-8899-97797368b8c4": {
      "count": -1
    },
    "ca6184a4-10cf-473c-b1f6-6bb73ab20679": {
      "count": 4
    },
    "1caf0bc3-1414-4221-ae1d-a94f99ced451": {
      "count": 0
    }
  }
}
```